# A single-page website which works like a slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, web, responsive-design

Here is [what I am trying to replicate](http://www.exosource.com/en).

It's a single-page site. You navigate "downwards" using the keyboard, mouse, mouse scroll or swiping. There are also some carousels which are navigated left/right. Each "slide" fits a full-height page up to the fold. But all the slides together are still a single HTML document.

I can try recreate this using custom code, but, there are many gotchas, such as detecting screen sizes, sticky footers, filling screen space, image resizing, etc.

Surely there is a plugin to do this, or perhaps a good tutorial, sample... or "something"? I'm using ASP.NET-MVC, but a generic solution would be a great starting point too!

**Update to appease the "question too-broad" editors:**
- How do I detect arriving at the end of a slide? ->jQuery Waypoints plugin
- How do I scroll to the next "slide"? I assume something like the jQuery scrollTo plugin?
- How do I do the left/right nav?
- How do I move slides left/right and up/down using the animation in that example?
- How do I bookmark/jump to the in-page links (which are triggers to go to a certain slide)

Comment: I don't want to do a true "Powerpoint style" site. There are lots of examples for that. This site is simpler and doesn't feel like Powerpoint.

Comment: It appears I can use the jQuery "Waypoints" plugin to detect arriving at new slides/pages, and then move things around in script. But the transitions are still what I'm battling with, and screen/viewport sizing.

Comment: Too broad/recommend find tool or library/no effort.

Comment: Really? How about you try find a tool, and see what you come up with? Nothing! That's why I asked the question. And no, it's not too broad. I'm asking for assistance on a very SPECIFIC UX paradigm. And what I want is not mainstream (as the Powerpoint clones are by now).

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow..](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208442/217110)

Answer (score 2):

It's called Parallax Scrolling technic.

[Tutorial](http://designzum.com/2014/01/26/10-awesome-parallax-scrolling-tutorials-with-code/)
[Simple version](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/)

And the slide show called Carusel ( if you use default boostrap in ASP .NET MVC ).

You can make your own one page application.
You can [see](http://www.awwwards.com/20-best-websites-with-parallax-scrolling-of-2013.html) these websites.

Comment: Lots of interesting ideas in those links... Thanks. Especially the waypoints plugin will help. **BUT, what I want to do is not parallax.** Parallax is when you, for example, have a seemingly moving background, or various items that appear layered. I just want to do a simple slideshow as in that example I posted.

Comment: On second thought, some of the transitions are similar to parallax, but that's not the crux of the question though...

Comment: Okey i get it :) Sry for the misunderstood. If u want to render some slideshow with wayspoints you can use this tool:)
[JMPRESS](https://github.com/jmpressjs/jmpress.js) . Prezi designed tool but it has some other features.